# Incorrect string value: '\\xA0Consu...' for column even though column has utf8mb4 encoding

Tags: mysql, collation, utf8mb4

I am running python script to insert record in table. I am reading data from spreadsheet that contain cell with special characters.

In my script I am running following commands before executing below commands:

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4;
SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `staging` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`d_date` date NOT NULL,
`m_date` date NOT NULL,
`market` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'US',
`cola` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`colb` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=265 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Table Encoding: UTF8MB4
Table Collation: UTF8MB4_UNICODE_CI

**Environment Variables:**

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%collation%';

```
collation_connection    latin1_swedish_ci
collation_database  utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_server    utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%';

```
character_set_client    latin1
character_set_connection    latin1
character_set_database  utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   latin1
character_set_server    utf8mb4
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/local/mysql-5.7.20-macos10.12-x86_64/share/charsets/
```

Query:

```
insert into staging (d_date, m_date, market, cola, colb ) 
values ('2019-07-18', '2019-07-01', 'US', 'ARCA', 'Sodius\xa0Consumer Auto');
```

Error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xA0Consu...' for column 'colb' at row 1")
```

Expected Result is row should be inserted into the database.

Comment: That string literal shown in the INSERT statement should evaluate without error. The backslash character will get dropped because the character following it doesn't form a valid MySQL escape sequence. `Sodiusxa0Con...` (If sql_mode includes NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES then the backslash character would be treated as a regular character.) I'm suspicious that the SQL statement shown in the question, with the string literal, is *not* the actual statement being executed.

Comment: @spencer7593 yes, the query is not an exact query. I have copied that from the command output.

Comment: Actual word is "Sodius¬†Consumer Auto"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This says that the encoding in the client is UTF-8:  `SET NAMES utf8mb4;`

This says that the encoding in the client is latin1:  `\xa0`.

This says that `cola` will be encoded UTF-8, regardless of what the client has:  `cola varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL`.

These say that you did `SET NAMES latin1`:

```
character_set_client    latin1
character_set_connection    latin1
character_set_results   latin1
```

If you really want the `\xA0` (hard space), then the entire text in the client must also be latin1, and you must say `SET NAMES latin1` (or ... -- there are several ways to do this).

If you don't care what type of space you use, then use a simple space.

If the rest of the client is talking UTF-8, and you want a "non-breaking space", then USE `\xc2a0` (the UTF-8 encoding).

Comment: Hi Rick, Thanks a lot for your response. Got it. It's working now.